# Selenoid-ui dashboard doesn't show the old sessions data

Tags: selenium, web-testing, selenoid

***DESCRIPTION***

While running test cases using selenoid, the selenoi-ui olny shows the current sessions. As soon as the sessions are completed, it removes sessions data from dashboard.

***QUESTION***

**Is there any way to show old run results in dashboard?**

Answer (score 1):

Selenoid is only showing currently running Selenium sessions and there is no way to somehow visualize previous ones. In order to store information about already executed test cases you are expected to use test execution report, e.g. [Allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/).

Answer (score 0):

Selenoid-ui does not have any long-term storage. But you can try to setup monitoring if needed:

https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-grafana-example